# XCode 6.4 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been having a linker command problem and can't seem to resolve it. Normally cleaning the project and rebuilding fixes it, or deleting the derived data but this time it will not build.

The file PTKCard should no longer exist so I am not sure why it is mentioning those in the error. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/rgainous/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit', framework linker option at /Users/rgainous/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit is not a dylib
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/rgainous/Documents/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at /Users/rgainous/Documents/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PTKCard in:
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPaymentKit.a(PTKCard.o)
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libStripe.a(STPPaymentCardTextField.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PTKCard in:
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPaymentKit.a(PTKCard.o)
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libStripe.a(STPPaymentCardTextField.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PTKView in:
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPaymentKit.a(PTKView.o)
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libStripe.a(STPPaymentCardTextField.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PTKView in:
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPaymentKit.a(PTKView.o)
    /Users/rgainous/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runn-fvmsldafsswpesagnpiepcisxrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libStripe.a(STPPaymentCardTextField.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you so mark it as answer.So it will be helpful for others

Comment: it didn't solve the issue @Bhumica

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your derived data. And then clean build then build again.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You need to do this:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings
3. Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths

May be this will help you.

**Solution 2**

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.